# Is it possible to load jquery and other js files into magento 2 footer?

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery, footer, jquery-ui

Guys I would like to know if it is possible to load js files in magento 2 footer. For example using the tag . And how would I do that?

Comment: You can move from admin at Stores > Configuration > Developer > Move JS code to the bottom of the page

Comment: but which way would I have to put in "<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"/>"
 to work?

Comment: which path would have to be inside src to work? <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"/>
 to work?

Comment: you want to add custom js in footer right ?

Comment: I want, but I wanted to know the path to put inside src.